# Can't login into admin URL on production with Django 4

Tags: python, django, django-4.0

Can't seem to login into Django admin URL on my production but it works fine on my local.  For context, currently my site does not have SSL. Debug is set to False as well.

This was working prior to Django 4 upgrade (was previously on Django 3.08)

`mysite.com/admin` keeps redirecting to `mysite.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/` with a 500 error.

Comment: Set Debug mode On and try to view the error

Comment: Do not set Debug as True on production, it looks like you are not logged to admin

Comment: Somewhere in the code admin urls are blocked

Comment: @SivaSankar I don't think the admin urls are blocked. It works fine on my local and it worked fine before the upgrade to Django 4. I don't have any server configs that block admin url's as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **SOLVED**

After going through my Django server logs it turned out being a missing packaged called `tzdata`. I had my timezone set to UTC so it was causing an error when accessing the admin panel.

My `settings.py` regarding timzones

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Thanks everyone for their thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Add your origin (domain) to the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` variable in the settings.py file.

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://my.domain.com:8000'
]
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0

Comment: I've tried this and still no luck. For more context my app is dockerized. It currently sends all traffic from NGINX to GUNICORN on port 8000

Comment: What is your ngnix config? Something like this?

location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_buffering off;
    }